# carrier module for node.js

Tags: node.js, module, carrier

I am doing some practice with node.js and in one of them I am told to use the carrier module that is claimed to be included when downloading node.js from the official site. However, my node.js library doesnt contain this module and I am curious as to where I can get it online?

Already spent about 25 minutes looking for it. Also, while I am at it I might as well ask where I can find a good size collection of other worthy node.js modules.

Thanks in advance

Comment: or **npm install carrier** if you have npm installed.

Answer (score 1):

It's at https://github.com/pgte/carrier linked to from the list of modules at https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules

Answer (score 1):

You can run the following command - **npm install carrier**  This will install the carrier package for your current `node.js` installation.

Comment: **if** you have `npm` installed. Older versions of Node have `npm` not bundlet.